# How to remove the meta data field from multi id queries

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the open_graph Explorer tool to test this out and I need to be able to get the first_name, last_name and installed from 1000 users. At the moment I group up the users in grouped of 50 for a single query and batch them into up to 20 queries in a batch request.

A single query looks as follows

```
?ids=100003825998801,100003825998802,547884299,100003825998803,100003825998804,100003825998805,100003825998806&fields=first_name,last_name,installed
```

Now, the question is, when you use multiple ids in a single query like I did, facebook seems to "force" certain fields on you, large fields, such as "metadata" and "fields". Is it possible to remove these fields from the result set of the query?

Also, any advice on how to make this more efficient would also be great. 
Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using FQL instead …?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, is_app_user FROM user
WHERE uid IN (100003825998801,100003825998802,547884299,100003825998803,
100003825998804,100003825998805,100003825998806)
```

– that gives you just the info you want, you only have to watch out for the fact that the *installed* field is named is_app_user in FQL.

Comment: I had not considered it. This does not really answer the question but it does solve my problem... more of a work around but I can't think of any reasons why not to do it using FQL.